report portal integration with Karate
I have the report portal(version 24.1) up and running on Docker. I am following this link (https://github.com/reportportal/agent-java-karate) for report portal integration.
While integrating it with the runner, I am getting exceptions that the RuntimeHook cannot be resolved. It is indirectly referenced from the required type com.epam.reportportal.karate.ReportPortalHook and the method hook(ExecutionHook) in the type Runner. Builder is not applicable for the argument (ReportPortalHook):
`
 import com.epam.reportportal.karate.ReportPortalHook;
 import com.intuit.karate.Runner;

 class ScenarioRunnerTest {
@Test
void testParallel() {
    return Runner
            .path("classpath:examples")
            .hook(new ReportPortalHook())
            .outputCucumberJson(true)
            .tags("~@ignore")
            .parallel(1);
}
}

`
I tried to configure the build path, but it is not working. Does anyone know what is the issue here?
there is a compilation error in the code following the document exactly.
